# How to build/install calendar.so for php?

Tags: php

I did the usual untar/configure/build for php 5.2.13.

Configure includes      --enable-calendar

Build works. I then run the libtool as instructed but no calendar.so is produced.

How do I make calendar.so?

Thank you!

(Linux system)

Answer (score 0):

Problem reported by the software was

> PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to
>   load dynamic library './calendar.so' -
>   ./calendar.so: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory
>   in Unknown on line 0

Problem went away after I

1. Replaced /etc/php.ini with php-5.2.13/php.ini-recommended
2. Uncommented the /etc/php.ini include line and changed it to be:

   include_path = ".:/php/includes:/usr/lib/php"

There still is no calendar.so produced. I think that it is included in the main php5.so file and the error msg is poor.